# Вывод c-строки с помощью формата

Tags: массивы, c

Добрый вечер, возникли небольшие трудности с выводом строки.

Код для примера: http://ideone.com/pZ0oOl

Как видно, при использовании массива в конце выводится какой-то мусор.

В чём моя ошибка?

*Кодировка cp866*

*Компилятор gcc (win) (mingw)*

*В QC2 под DOSBox проблем не замечено*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В С последний символ строки должен быть нулевым. Иначе printf и другие подобные функции не смогут определить длину (конец) строки.

В Вашем случае нужно дописать что то вида

```
arr[15] = '\0';
```

или

```
arr[15] = 0;
```

перед выводом.

```
i = 0;
while (i++ < 16)
{
    arr[i - 1] = '-';
}
arr[15] = 0;
printf("%s\n", arr);
```

если нужно именно 16 символов в строке, тогда выделяйте на один больше.

Comment: А разве нуль-символ сам не "вставляется"?
В примере же создаётся массив размерностью 16, т.к. индексация начинается с нуля, то `arr[15]` - содержит последний элемент массива, а `arr[16]` - содержит как раз нуль-символ. Разве не так?

Кстати, вашим способом, если перед выводом написать `arr[16] = '\0';`, то выводится правильно, не меняя размерность массива (ошибок и предупреждений нет). Но опять же, по идее нуль символ должен и так там быть.

Comment: не должно там быть нулевого символа.

тем более, если массив имеет размерность 16 элементов и начинается с нулевого элемента, то 16 элемент будет иметь индекс 15. А с индексом 16 элемента уже не будет (это будет за пределами массива).

Можно конечно понадеяться, что там, за пределами будет как раз нулевой символ. Но это неизвестно.

Comment: Надо мне мат-часть подучить, в таком случае.

Про ошибки: они не возникают при выводе в поток, однако при выводе в файл - да.

Comment: @froxxendsg: ошибка есть всегда, если вы не устанавливаете последний символ в `\0`. Иногда она просто не проявляется.

Comment: Я про ошибки, на которые ругается компилятор (error)

Правильно понимаю, что нуль-символ нужно добавлять всегда "вручную"?

Comment: @froxxendsg: «Всегда» — это, пожалуй, слишком серьёзно сказано. Если вы заводите массив, и инициализируете его вручную, вы должны добавить `\0` в конце. В других случаях может быть и не нужно, например:

    char array[16] = "----------";